# EWS api - Unable to connect ExchangeServer on-prem

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, centos7, exchangewebservices

I am implementing the Microsoft EWS api in order to get emails from the on-prem Exchange Server. Considering that the Microsoft has abandoned the development, I am using the sherlock1982 fork from [ews api](https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api). My app is written in .net core 2.1 and **when running on my local PC (win10), everything is working well.** Considering that its a Linux, it is not possible to automatically get the Autodiscover url, so I am manually setting it in the code, as suggested on the github page.

```
public async void GetInbox()
        {
            string ewsUrl = "https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

            try
            {
                var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

                service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                // service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domainUsername", "password", "domain");
                service.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl);

                Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("emailAddress");

                var cache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
                cache.Add(service.Url, "NTLM", new 
                System.Net.NetworkCredential("domainUsername", "password", 
                "domain"));
                service.Credentials = cache;

                FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mb);

                Folder inbox = await Folder.Bind(service, fid);
                if (inbox != null)
                {
                    _database.LogEvent("LOG", "GetInbox", $"InboxCount: {inbox.TotalCount}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _database.LogEvent("Error", "GetInbox", $"{e.Message}");
            }

        }
```

When deployed to the test server running CentOS7, I am getting following message:

The request failed. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

```
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\EwsHttpWebRequest.cs:line 147
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 798
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request, CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 808
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 688
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\Requests\SimpleServiceRequestBase.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\Requests\MultiResponseServiceRequest.cs:line 134
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder(FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet, CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 325
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet, CancellationToken token) in D:\dev_in_progress\ews-managed-api-master\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 345
   at ExchangeFiles.Email.Download_PI_Files_Email() in D:\dev_in_progress\get_emails_v1\ExchangeFiles\Email.cs:line 199
```

I have tried ignoring the certificate with
ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

but without luck (I am getting the same error).

**UPDATE**:
I have added a following piece of code

```
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                {
                    if (cert.GetCertHashString().ToLower() == "someHashCert")
                    {
                       return true;
                    }

                    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                    {
                      
                        return true;   //Is valid
                    }

                    return false;
                }
```

inside the code for creating HttpClientHandler. Its entering inside the if "cert.GetCertHashString().ToLower()" which is good. I have copied the value of someHashCert from the browser.
I also tried setting the

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

But error with this code (and above when checking the cert) is:
The request failed. The handler does not support custom handling of certificates with this combination of libcurl (7.29.0) and its SSL backend ("NSS/3.44"). An SSL backend based on "OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips" is required. Consider using System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.

If I set

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", true);
```

I am getting:
The request failed. GSSAPI operation failed with error - An unsupported mechanism was requested (Unknown error).

I have also tried to setup the callback for certificate from MS doc [cert for ews api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-validate-a-server-certificate-for-the-ews-managed-api) but then I am getting "Unable to get local issuer certificate" msg.

Not sure is this is step forward or backward... I have a feeling that I have tried everything...

**UPDATE2**
The ExchangeSever version is 2016, its using NTLM authentification and TLS1.0/1.1

I tried  curl -v -k -i --anyauth -u : mail.server.domain:443 and it says

```
* About to connect() to mail.server.domain: port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
* Connected to mail.server.domain (xx.xx.xx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: mail.server.domain::443
> Accept: */*
```

Any idea is welcome... Thanks

Comment: Against what version of Exchange ? 2019 and Office365 require that you use TLS 1.2

Comment: hello @GlenScales, as stated in the code, its ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1. But after calling "openssl s_client -connect mail.domain.local:443" from CentOS machine, its indeed telling me that the protocol is TLSv1.2. Not sure what to do next... Thanks

Comment: Okay so it sounds like the opposite might be you problem because the server doesn't support TLS 1.2. So you can either enable that on the server https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-server-tls-guidance-part-2-enabling-tls-1-2-and/ba-p/607761 which would be preferable or downgrade your client (not a great idea) with System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol (although you need to verify if that port is using httpclient or httpwebrequest as this will only work in the later i believe)

Comment: sorry for a question, I dont have much knowledge about protocols/certificates but why do you believe that exchange server dont support TLS 1.2, under protocol it said TLSv1.2. I got some more intersting logs from openssl command, like:
 verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
 verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
* NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
* Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.

Comment: TLS 1.2 isn't enabled by default on Exchange 2013 (because of its age) so there's probably a good chance if your running such an old version that things like enabling TLS 1.2 has been overlooked. Is it also using a self signed certificate? given that error i would try importing the cert

Comment: hello Glen, I guess you didnt saw the updates regarding the question, I talked with my colleague and he informed me with following: ExchangeSever version is 2016, its using NTLM authentification and TLS1.0/1.1. I tried with downgrading TLS, it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, nothing suggested from here worked.

I found some comment about similar issue on github and how updating the project to .NET core 3.1 fixed the error, so I decided to give it a try...

It was not a small work, I had several projects inside the solution, but I can confirm that after updating from .NET core 2.1 to .NET core 3.1, everything is working as it should.

Comment: is it viable to keep using EWS on .net core or is it recommended to use Microsoft Graph (in case of using only office 365)?

Comment: @sofsntp, I know but unfortunately exchange is on prem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your TLS on Cent OS.
TLSv1.2 should be available on CentOS 7.

> Some documentation.

Linux OpenSSL 1.1.1 supports TLS v1.3 in different Linux OS.

RHEL 8 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 is the first Enterprise Linux distribution that ships with the TLS v1.3 protocol fully integrated into the operating system.

Older CentOS and RHEL OS versions have OpenSSL v1.0.2 installed by default, so TLS v1.3 is not supported natively.
OpenSSL can be yum updated to OpenSSL v1.1.1 to support TLS v1.3.

> Blockquote

How to install OpenSSL v1.1.1 on CentOS RedHat Linux:
Use the OpenSSL Version Command to verify the OpenSSL Version:

## openssl version

Install wget(If it is not installed):

## yum install wget

Download the latest version using wget:

## wget https://ftp.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz

Decompress the file:

## tar xvf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz

Further configuration is necessary, Please consult your System Administrators prior to making any changes.

disabled by default system wide. If you enable TLS v1.3 on a system for testing, then

TLS  should be supported by OS and .net framework.
Check OS and upgrade it if it does not support TLS 1.2
then use Right .net framework which supports TLS 1.2 /1.3
Install Self signed cert on Cent OS also.

Will TLS 1.3 be supported on .NET?

For .NET, the official guidance at this point (via the best practices page above) is to rely on the underlying OS to provide the TLS version (which will automatically default to the strongest available version of the TLS protocol), and avoid hardcoding/specifying an explicit TLS version in application code.

Starting with .NET Framework 4.7, the default configuration is to use the OS TLS version.

Other links which may be helpful: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4675 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: Compiling OpenSSL manually is IMHO a bad suggestion, as it usually doesn't receive any maintenance (e.g. security fixes for future security flaws) then, because the steps are treated as a one-time thing. I would recommend to use the `openssl11` and `openssl11-devel` RPM packages from the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository instead, which are maintained and receive security updates as part of `yum update`.